# Purpose of custom BitSet implementation in this Leetcode answer

Tags: c++

Last night I was working on the ["Longest Palindromic Subsequence" problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-subsequence/submissions/). After completing it I took a look at the fastest answer, and to my surprise it was a giant custom bitset implementation. I decided to try and reverse engineer it a bit and see if I could implement it using `std::bitset`, but I've run into some issues.

Here's the code:

```
#if __cplusplus>199711L  //c++11
#include<unordered_map>
#endif
const int N=1005;
template<int S>
struct BitSet{
    #define W 6
    #define mask 63
    #define get_size(n) ((n)<1?0:((n)+mask)>>W)
    typedef unsigned long long uint;  //typedef unsigned int uint;
    uint a[get_size(S)];int size;
    void reset(){memset(a,0,sizeof(uint)*size);}
    BitSet():size(get_size(S)){reset();}
    BitSet(uint x):size(get_size(S)){reset();a[0]=x;}
    BitSet(const BitSet<S> &x):size(get_size(S)){*this=x;}
    BitSet& set(int x,int y){
        //if (y<0||y>1){printf("error!\n");return *this;}
        int X=x>>W,Y=x&mask;
        if (y)a[X]|=1ull<<Y;else a[X]&=~(1ull<<Y);
        return *this;
    }
    int find(int x){int X=x>>W,Y=x&mask;return (a[X]>>Y)&1ull;}
    int operator [](int x){return find(x);}
    BitSet& operator =(const BitSet &y){
        memcpy(a,y.a,sizeof(uint)*size);
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S> operator |(const BitSet<S> &y)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)|=y;}
    BitSet<S> operator &(const BitSet<S> &y)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)&=y;}
    BitSet<S> operator ^(const BitSet<S> &y)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)^=y;}
    BitSet<S> operator +(const BitSet<S> &y)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)+=y;}
    BitSet<S> operator -(const BitSet<S> &y)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)-=y;}
    BitSet<S> operator <<(int x)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)<<=x;}
    BitSet<S> operator >>(int x)const{return BitSet<S>(*this)>>=x;}
    BitSet<S> operator ~()const{return BitSet<S>(*this).flip();}
    BitSet<S>& operator =(const char *s){
        memset(a,0,sizeof(uint)*size);
        for (int i=0;i<S;++i){
            if (s[i]!='0'&&s[i]!='1')break;
            int X=i>>W,Y=i&mask;
            if (s[i]=='1')a[X]|=1ull<<Y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator =(const int *s){
        memset(a,0,sizeof(uint)*size);
        for (int i=0;i<S;++i){
            if (s[i]!=0&&s[i]!=1)break;
            int X=i>>W,Y=i&mask;
            if (s[i]==1)a[X]|=1ull<<Y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator <<=(int x){
        int shift=x>>W; int delta=x&mask,delta1=mask+1-delta;
        if (!x)return *this;
        if (delta==0)for (uint *p=a+size-1,*q=p-shift,*end=a+shift-1;p!=end;--p,--q)*p=*q;
        else {
            for (uint *p=a+size-1,*q1=p-shift,*q2=p-shift-1,*end=a+shift;p!=end;--p,--q1,--q2)*p=(*q1<<delta)|(*q2>>delta1);
            a[shift]=a[0]<<delta;
        }
        memset(a,0,sizeof(uint)*shift); //for (uint *p=a,*end=a+shift;p!=end;++p)*p=0;
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator >>=(int x){
        int shift=x>>W; int delta=x&mask,delta1=mask+1-delta;
        if (!x)return *this;
        correction();
        if (delta==0)for (uint *p=a,*q=p+shift,*end=a+size-shift;p!=end;++p,++q)*p=*q;
        else {
            for (uint *p=a,*q1=p+shift,*q2=p+shift+1,*end=a+size-shift-1;p!=end;++p,++q1,++q2)*p=(*q1>>delta)|(*q2<<delta1);
            a[size-shift-1]=a[size-1]>>delta;
        }
        memset(a+size-shift,0,sizeof(uint)*shift);
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator |=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint *startA=a;const uint *startB=y.a,*endA=a+size;
        while (startA!=endA){*startA|=*startB;++startA;++startB;}
        //for (int i=0;i<size;++i)a[i]|=y.a[i];
        return *this;
    }
    /*BitSet<S>& operator |=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint *p0=a,*p1=p0+1,*p2=p0+2,*p3=p0+3;const uint *q0=y.a,*q1=q0+1,*q2=q0+2,*q3=q0+3,*pend=a+((size>>2)<<2);
        while (p0!=pend){
            *p0|=*q0; p0+=4; q0+=4;
            *p1|=*q1; p1+=4; q1+=4;
            *p2|=*q2; p2+=4; q2+=4;
            *p3|=*q3; p3+=4; q3+=4;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<(size&3);++i)*p0++|=*q0++;
        return *this;
    }*/
    BitSet<S>& operator &=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint *startA=a;const uint *startB=y.a,*endA=a+size;
        while (startA!=endA){*startA&=*startB;++startA;++startB;}
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator ^=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint *startA=a;const uint *startB=y.a,*endA=a+size;
        while (startA!=endA){*startA^=*startB;++startA;++startB;}
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator +=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint t=0,*p=a,*end=a+size; const uint *q=y.a;
        while (p!=end){
            uint p1=*p; *p=p1+*q+t;
            t=(*p<p1)||(p1+t<t);
            ++p; ++q;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator -=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint t=0,*p=a,*end=a+size; const uint *q=y.a;
        while (p!=end){
            uint p1=*p; *p=p1-*q-t;
            t=(*p>p1)||(p1+t<t);
            ++p; ++q;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    operator bool(){return count()>0;}
    BitSet<S>& flip(){
        //for (uint *start=a,*end=a+size;start!=end;*start=~*start,++start);
        uint *p0=a,*p1=p0+1,*p2=p0+2,*p3=p0+3,*pend=a+((size>>2)<<2);
        while (p0!=pend){
            *p0=~*p0; p0+=4;
            *p1=~*p1; p1+=4;
            *p2=~*p2; p2+=4;
            *p3=~*p3; p3+=4;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<(size&3);++i,++p0)*p0=~*p0;
        return *this;
    }
    //void flip(){*this=~*this;}
    void flip(int x){a[x>>W]^=1ull<<(x&mask);}
    int popcount(uint x)const{
        x-=(x&0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaull)>>1;
        x=((x&0xccccccccccccccccull)>>2)+(x&0x3333333333333333ull);
        x=((x>>4)+x)&0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0full;
        return (x*0x0101010101010101ull)>>56;
    }
    int count(){
        int res=0;
        correction();
        for (int i=0;i<size;++i)res+=__builtin_popcountll(a[i]);  //popcount
        return res;
    }
    int clz(){
        correction();
        int res=0;
        if (a[size-1])res=__builtin_clzll(a[size-1])-(mask+1-(S&mask));
        else {
            res+=S&mask;
            for (int i=size-2;i>=0;--i)
                if (a[i]){res+=__builtin_clzll(a[i]); break;}
                else res+=mask+1;
        }
        return res;
    }
    int ctz(){
        correction();
        int res=0;
        for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
            if (a[i]){res+=__builtin_ctzll(a[i]); break;}
            else res+=mask+1;
        return min(res,S);
    }
    int ffs(){
        int res=ctz()+1;
        if (res==S+1)res=0;
        return res;
    }
    uint to_uint(){
        correction();
        return a[0];
    }
    void print(){
        for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
            for (int j=0;j<=mask&&(i<<W)+j+1<=S;++j)printf("%I64d",(a[i]>>j)&1ull);
        printf("\n");
    }
    void correction(){if (S&mask)a[size-1]&=(1ull<<(S&mask))-1;}
    #undef mask
    #undef W
    #undef get_size
};

int a[N],b[N];
BitSet<N> row[2],X,Y;
unordered_map<int,vector<int> > S;
unordered_map<int,BitSet<N> > match;

class Solution {
public:
    int longestPalindromeSubseq(string s) {
        int n=s.size(),m=n;
        S.clear();match.clear();row[1].reset();
        for (int i=0;i<n;++i)a[i]=int(s[i]),S[a[i]].push_back(i);
        for (int i=0;i<m;++i)b[i]=int(s[n-1-i]);
        for (int i=0;i<m;++i)if (match.find(b[i])==match.end()){
            unordered_map<int,BitSet<N> >::iterator x=match.insert(make_pair(b[i],BitSet<N>())).first;
            for (vector<int>::iterator j=S[b[i]].begin();j!=S[b[i]].end();++j)x->second.set(*j,1);
        }
        for (int i=0,now=0;i<m;++i,now^=1)
            X=(row[now^1]|match[b[i]]).set(n,1),row[now]=(X&((X-(row[now^1]<<1).set(0,1))^X)).set(n,0);
        return row[(m-1)&1].count();
    }
};
```

And here's my attempt at cleaning it up/understanding it:

Bitset.h:

```
#pragma once


//#if __cplusplus>199711L  //c++11
#include<unordered_map>
//#endif

#include <intrin.h>

const int N = 1005; //this size doesn't even matter?? It's just enigmatically assigning a type of int, I guess??
template<int S>
struct BitSet {
#define W 6
#define mask 63
#define get_size(n) ((n)<1?0:((n)+mask)>>W)
    
    //members
    typedef unsigned long long uint;  //typedef unsigned int uint; //not sure why they didn't just use size_t here...
    uint a[get_size(S)]; //represents the "BitSet" I think... 
    int size;
    
    //constructors
    BitSet() :size(get_size(S)) { reset(); }
    BitSet(uint x) :size(get_size(S)) { reset(); a[0] = x; }
    BitSet(const BitSet<S>& x) :size(get_size(S)) { *this = x; }

    //utility functions
    BitSet& set(int x, int y) {
        //if (y<0||y>1){printf("error!\n");return *this;}
        int X = x >> W, Y = x & mask; //bit shift with the magic numbers??? //What is the significance of 6, 63, and 1005?
        if (y)a[X] |= 1ull << Y; else a[X] &= ~(1ull << Y);
        return *this;
    }
    void reset() { memset(a, 0, sizeof(uint) * size); }
    int find(int x) { int X = x >> W, Y = x & mask; return (a[X] >> Y) & 1ull; }
    //void flip(){*this=~*this;}
    void flip(int x) { a[x >> W] ^= 1ull << (x & mask); }
    int popcount(uint x)const {
        x -= (x & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaull) >> 1;
        x = ((x & 0xccccccccccccccccull) >> 2) + (x & 0x3333333333333333ull);
        x = ((x >> 4) + x) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0full;
        return (x * 0x0101010101010101ull) >> 56;
    }
    int count() {
        int res = 0;
        correction();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)res += __popcnt(a[i]);  //popcount // __builtin_popcountll is only available on GCC apparently. Substituted with library version.
        return res;
    }
    int clz() {
        correction();
        int res = 0;
        if (a[size - 1])res = __builtin_clzll(a[size - 1]) - (mask + 1 - (S & mask));
        else {
            res += S & mask;
            for (int i = size - 2; i >= 0; --i)
                if (a[i]) { res += __builtin_clzll(a[i]); break; }
                else res += mask + 1;
        }
        return res;
    }
    int ctz() {
        correction();
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            if (a[i]) { res += __builtin_ctzll(a[i]); break; }
            else res += mask + 1;
        return min(res, S);
    }
    int ffs() {
        int res = ctz() + 1;
        if (res == S + 1)res = 0;
        return res;
    }
    uint to_uint() {
        correction();
        return a[0];
    }
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j <= mask && (i << W) + j + 1 <= S; ++j)printf("%I64d", (a[i] >> j) & 1ull);
        printf("\n");
    }
    void correction() { if (S & mask)a[size - 1] &= (1ull << (S & mask)) - 1; }
    BitSet<S>& flip() {
        //for (uint *start=a,*end=a+size;start!=end;*start=~*start,++start);
        uint* p0 = a, * p1 = p0 + 1, * p2 = p0 + 2, * p3 = p0 + 3, * pend = a + ((size >> 2) << 2);
        while (p0 != pend) {
            *p0 = ~*p0; p0 += 4;
            *p1 = ~*p1; p1 += 4;
            *p2 = ~*p2; p2 += 4;
            *p3 = ~*p3; p3 += 4;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (size & 3); ++i, ++p0)*p0 = ~*p0;
        return *this;
    }

    //operators
    int operator [](int x) { return find(x); }
    BitSet& operator =(const BitSet& y) {
        memcpy(a, y.a, sizeof(uint) * size);
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator =(const char* s) {
        memset(a, 0, sizeof(uint) * size);
        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            if (s[i] != '0' && s[i] != '1')break;
            int X = i >> W, Y = i & mask;
            if (s[i] == '1')a[X] |= 1ull << Y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator =(const int* s) {
        memset(a, 0, sizeof(uint) * size);
        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            if (s[i] != 0 && s[i] != 1)break;
            int X = i >> W, Y = i & mask;
            if (s[i] == 1)a[X] |= 1ull << Y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S> operator |(const BitSet<S>& y)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) |= y; }
    BitSet<S> operator &(const BitSet<S>& y)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) &= y; }
    BitSet<S> operator ^(const BitSet<S>& y)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) ^= y; }
    BitSet<S> operator +(const BitSet<S>& y)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) += y; }
    BitSet<S> operator -(const BitSet<S>& y)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) -= y; }
    BitSet<S> operator <<(int x)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) <<= x; }
    BitSet<S> operator >>(int x)const { return BitSet<S>(*this) >>= x; }
    BitSet<S> operator ~()const { return BitSet<S>(*this).flip(); }
    BitSet<S>& operator <<=(int x) {
        int shift = x >> W; int delta = x & mask, delta1 = mask + 1 - delta;
        if (!x)return *this;
        if (delta == 0)for (uint* p = a + size - 1, *q = p - shift, *end = a + shift - 1; p != end; --p, --q)*p = *q;
        else {
            for (uint* p = a + size - 1, *q1 = p - shift, *q2 = p - shift - 1, *end = a + shift; p != end; --p, --q1, --q2)*p = (*q1 << delta) | (*q2 >> delta1);
            a[shift] = a[0] << delta;
        }
        memset(a, 0, sizeof(uint) * shift); //for (uint *p=a,*end=a+shift;p!=end;++p)*p=0; //if this is a left shift... why is it setting the beginning of the "a" array to 0???... unless the damn array is "backwards". Sheesh.
        //wait... this is a right shift according to https://orthallelous.wordpress.com/2019/10/24/magic-numbers-encoding-truth-tables-into-giant-single-values/ ... fuck.
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator >>=(int x) {
        int shift = x >> W; int delta = x & mask, delta1 = mask + 1 - delta;
        if (!x)return *this;
        correction();
        if (delta == 0)for (uint* p = a, *q = p + shift, *end = a + size - shift; p != end; ++p, ++q)*p = *q;
        else {
            for (uint* p = a, *q1 = p + shift, *q2 = p + shift + 1, *end = a + size - shift - 1; p != end; ++p, ++q1, ++q2)*p = (*q1 >> delta) | (*q2 << delta1);
            a[size - shift - 1] = a[size - 1] >> delta;
        }
        memset(a + size - shift, 0, sizeof(uint) * shift);
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator |=(const BitSet<S>& y) {
        uint* startA = a; const uint* startB = y.a, * endA = a + size;
        while (startA != endA) { *startA |= *startB; ++startA; ++startB; }
        //for (int i=0;i<size;++i)a[i]|=y.a[i];
        return *this;
    }
    /*BitSet<S>& operator |=(const BitSet<S> &y){
        uint *p0=a,*p1=p0+1,*p2=p0+2,*p3=p0+3;const uint *q0=y.a,*q1=q0+1,*q2=q0+2,*q3=q0+3,*pend=a+((size>>2)<<2);
        while (p0!=pend){
            *p0|=*q0; p0+=4; q0+=4;
            *p1|=*q1; p1+=4; q1+=4;
            *p2|=*q2; p2+=4; q2+=4;
            *p3|=*q3; p3+=4; q3+=4;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<(size&3);++i)*p0++|=*q0++;
        return *this;
    }*/
    BitSet<S>& operator &=(const BitSet<S>& y) {
        uint* startA = a; const uint* startB = y.a, * endA = a + size;
        while (startA != endA) { *startA &= *startB; ++startA; ++startB; }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator ^=(const BitSet<S>& y) {
        uint* startA = a; const uint* startB = y.a, * endA = a + size;
        while (startA != endA) { *startA ^= *startB; ++startA; ++startB; }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator +=(const BitSet<S>& y) {
        uint t = 0, * p = a, * end = a + size; const uint* q = y.a;
        while (p != end) {
            uint p1 = *p; *p = p1 + *q + t;
            t = (*p < p1) || (p1 + t < t);
            ++p; ++q;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    BitSet<S>& operator -=(const BitSet<S>& y) {
        uint t = 0, * p = a, * end = a + size; const uint* q = y.a;
        while (p != end) {
            uint p1 = *p; *p = p1 - *q - t;
            t = (*p > p1) || (p1 + t < t);
            ++p; ++q;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    operator bool() { return count() > 0; }
    
#undef mask
#undef W
#undef get_size
};
```

LeetCode516.cpp

```
// LeetCode516.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "BitSet.h"
#include <bitset>


// If parameter is not true, test fails
// This check function would be provided by the test framework
#define IS_TRUE(x) { if (!x) std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " failed on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl; else std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " passed" << std:: endl;}


int longestPalindromeSubseq(std::string s) {
    int a[N] = { 0 }, b[N] = { 0 }; //2 integer arrays - initialzing to 0 isn't necessary, but seems to make the debug output more readable?
    BitSet<N> row[2], X, Y; //3 bitsets... one of them is actually 2 (lol)
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> S; //This map tracks the number of occurrences of each letter?
    std::unordered_map<int, BitSet<N>> match;

    int n = s.size(), m = n;
    S.clear(); 
    match.clear(); 
    //row[1].reset(); //WTF is this? Garbage.

    //For each piece of the string, cast it from a char to an int and shove it in the first array, then push back a copy of each array into the UOMap S.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = static_cast<int>(s[i]); //changed C-style cast to static_cast
        S[a[i]].push_back(i); 
    }

    //Set the second array to a backwards copy of A I guess? (while converting the characters to integers ofc)
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        b[i] = int(s[n - 1 - i]);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {

        //so if it's the first loop iteration or the find (working on the "backwards" array) matches the end, do this:
        if (match.find(b[i]) == match.end()) { //how does this even run the first time? Match is getting cleared and never set? I guess it's working because "find(b[i])" and "end()" are both 0? - Kind of - turns out that if the find function fails, it returns "end"...
            //Insert a new bitset with a "key" of "b[i]" into the match map. 
            auto x = match.insert(std::make_pair(b[i], BitSet<N>())).first; // replaced std::unordered_map<int, BitSet<N> >::iterator with auto... that's nice.
            //Then using the iterator we just created above, loop through all entries in UOMap S under that key and ???
            //Since we found it in "match", lets check for it(?) in UOMap S... and then set some bit in match based on how many entries there are in S?
            for (auto j = S[b[i]].begin(); j != S[b[i]].end(); ++j) {
                x->second.set(*j, 1); //this is setting some bit value in "match" to 1 I guess.
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0, now = 0; i < m; ++i, now ^= 1) { //Is "*=" being intentionally obfuscated here to "^=" or is it actually different?? Ugh... nasty.
        X = (row[now ^ 1] | match[b[i]]).set(n, 1); // if the caret is supposed to represent XOR, why does this still work whenever I replace it with a *... very funky.
        row[now] = (X & ((X - (row[now ^ 1] << 1).set(0, 1)) ^ X)).set(n, 0);
    }
    return row[(m - 1) & 1].count();
}


template<int S>
std::bitset<S>& operator-(const std::bitset<S>&y) { return std::bitset<S>(*this) -= y; }


#define W 6
#define mask 63
#define get_size(n) ((n)<1?0:((n)+mask)>>W)
template<size_t S>
std::bitset<S>& operator-(std::bitset<S>& y, const std::bitset<S>& z) { 
    //return std::bitset<S>(*this) -= y; 


    size_t thing[get_size(S)];

    size_t t = 0, * p = thing, * end = thing + get_size(y);
    const size_t* q = z[0]; //z.a
    while (p != end) {
        size_t p1 = *p;
        *p = p1 - *q - t;
        t = (*p > p1) || (p1 + t < t);
        ++p; 
        ++q;
    }
    return y;
}

template<size_t S>
std::bitset<S>& operator+(std::bitset<S>& y, const std::bitset<S>& z) {
    size_t thing[get_size(S)];
    
    size_t t = 0, * p = thing, * end = thing + get_size(y); 
    const size_t* q = z[0];
    while (p != end) {
        size_t p1 = *p; *p = p1 + *q + t;
        t = (*p < p1) || (p1 + t < t);
        ++p; 
        ++q;
    }
    return y;
}



template<size_t S>
std::bitset<S>& operator -=(const std::bitset<S>& y) {
    uint t = 0, * p = a, * end = a + size;
    const uint* q = y.a;
    while (p != end) {
        uint p1 = *p; *p = p1 - *q - t;
        t = (*p > p1) || (p1 + t < t);
        ++p; ++q;
    }
    return *this;
}

int LPS_STL(std::string s) {
    const int M = 1005;
    int c[M], d[M];
    std::bitset<M> row[2], X, Y;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> > S;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::bitset<M> > match;

    

    int n = s.size(), m = n;
    S.clear(); 
    match.clear(); 
    row[1].reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)c[i] = int(s[i]), S[c[i]].push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)d[i] = int(s[n - 1 - i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)if (match.find(d[i]) == match.end()) {
        std::unordered_map<int, std::bitset<M> >::iterator x = match.insert(std::make_pair(d[i], std::bitset<M>())).first;
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator j = S[d[i]].begin(); j != S[d[i]].end(); ++j)x->second.set(*j, 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0, now = 0; i < m; ++i, now ^= 1)
        X = (row[now ^ 1] | match[d[i]]).set(n, 1), row[now] = (X & (( X - (row[now ^ 1] << 1).set(0, 1)) ^ X)).set(n, 0);
    return row[(m - 1) & 1].count();
}



void test1() {
    int test = longestPalindromeSubseq("");

    IS_TRUE(test == 0);
}

void test2() {
    int test = longestPalindromeSubseq("bbbab");

    IS_TRUE(test == 4);
}

void test3() {
    int test = longestPalindromeSubseq("cbbd");

    IS_TRUE(test == 2);
}

void test4() {
    int test = longestPalindromeSubseq("cbbd");

    IS_TRUE(test == 0); //purposefully fail
}

void test5() {
    int test = longestPalindromeSubseq("cacbcbba");

    IS_TRUE(test == 5); 
}

void test6() {
    int test = longestPalindromeSubseq("eeeecdeabfbeeb");

    IS_TRUE(test == 7);
}

//Std::bitset tests
//void test7() {
//  int test = LPS_STL("");
//  IS_TRUE(test == 0);
//}

//void test8() {
//  int test = LPS_STL("bbbab")
//  IS_TRUE(test == 4);
//}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Longest Palindrome Subsequence\n";
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
    test4();
    test5();
    test6();
    
    test7();
    test8();
}
```

Main question: Is there a core reason this person chose to implement a custom bitset instead of the std library?

Extraneous questions:

- Is some of this code intentionally obfuscated?

  - It feels a bit naive to ask this, but do some of you intentionally code this way?
  - Why are they using the value of `N` (an int) as the type for their bitsets?
  - Some of their formulas are incredibly long.
- Attempting to implement the necessary operators for the `std::bitset` implementation didn't go well.  Can someone elucidate the reason these don't exist? I feel like there's a good reason for it regarding expected output, but I can't articulate it.
- Is this question more appropriate for another SO site, such as Code Review?

Comment: i would compare the custom implementation with how `std::bitset` is specified. So far the difference I found is that `std::bitset::operator[]` is `constexpr` since C++11, but not in this custom implementation, though thats a step back actually

Comment: professional code and competitive code are two different things. Competitive programming only has to be fast in some very specific cases The code above does that. Offer specific performance in some specific case, at the cost of everything else. Professional code has to be maintainable, clean, readable.

Comment: I would not expect clean code in a solution on Leetcode. Not saying that this code is a mess, but online coding challenges often favor unconventional and "don't do it at work" solutions rather than the opposite

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, Yes I've attempted to do that through cppreference.com. Is there a better place to look at STL implementations. Also, why would you consider the use of  ```constexpr``` with ```operator[]``` a "step back"?
@Jeffrey, yes I understand that, but often times I have to read poorly written/purposefully obfuscated code and I'd like to get better at it and understand ```bitset``` at the same time.

Comment: it is a step back to not have it `constexpr`

Answer (score 1):

> - Is some of this code intentionally obfuscated?

It is just faster to type

```
#define W 6
```

than

```
constexpr size_t bitcoverage { std::bitwidth(sizeof(int64_t)*CHAR_BIT)-1 }; // bits needed to represent 8*8=64 2^7 so 7-1=6 which 0-63 bits.
```

(if I got it right ...)

> - It feels a bit naive to ask this, but do some of you intentionally code this way?

When I started programming I did, now I have realized that code is read more than written and it could confuse people, including me, who read it later.

> - Why are they using the value of N (an int) as the type for their bitsets?

N is just how many entries there is max, see the link you provided.

It actually uses an int64_t to store the bits. Which for many operaton on most larger CPU's is far more efficient than the same doing the same operation on an byte as you can do or/and/etc on a lot of bits with just one instuction.

> - Some of their formulas are incredibly long.

I am not sure which your are speculating about.

> - Attempting to implement the necessary operators for the std::bitset implementation didn't go well. Can someone elucidate the reason these don't exist? I feel like there's a good reason for it regarding expected output, but I can't articulate it.

Again, what exact are you referring to?